# How do I prepare a Windows 10 computer for a long-running time-critical measurement?

Tags: windows-10, uptime

For the company I work for, I have to set up a computer which is supposed to do a long-term measurement on one of our products. The following parameters apply:

- Measurement duration: ~2 weeks
- Interface: multi-channel audio interface using ASIO driver
- Measurement Software: Custom, written in C#
- Operating system: Windows 10
- Timing Margin: ~20 ms (if this is blown once every few hours its still ok, but should not happen too regularly)
- Computer has to be connected to the internet to allow remote desktop
- The hardware will be a standard desktop or notebook PC - nothing too fancy but nothing too old either

What ideas come to mind about how I would prepare the computer running the measurement? Besides the obvious - disabling stand-by and auto-shutdown - I'm wondering: I should probably prevent the installation of updates, and especially the associated restarts, but I'm not sure I can disable them completely in Windows 10... Is there a method for doing this? Anything else I should worry about?

Any thoughts and tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: Based on experience with two labs, one running Unix and the other windows - windows was not long term stable ie for cfd jobs using 90% of the processor for 40 days unix never failed- windows ...

Comment: Regards timing margins, best bet would be to frequently sync with an external time source, such as the NTP pool http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/